# Labeled multiline text as equation

Tags: labels, alignment, text

I am trying to get the result like (2) on the screen below. No idea how to get that. I've tried align, split, multline, but nothing was efficient. Could you help me with getting there? Thanks in advance.

[image: aligned_text_with_label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `{minipage}`:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
If $F \subseteq E(G)$ is feasible on $V_j^1 \cup V_j^2 $, 
then $d_F(x)$ is odd if $x \in V_j^1$ and $d_F(x)$ is even
if $x \in V_j^2$
\end{minipage}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Thanks! That looks simplier and better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured that out.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
~ & \text{If } F \subseteq E(G) \text{ is feasible on } V_j^o \cup V_j^e, 
\text{then} d_F(x) \text{ is odd if } \\ 
&x \in V_j^o \text{ and } d_F(x) \text{ is even if } x \in V_j^e.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which results with:

[image: answer]